# Lemma 3.53 Rotman's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

In Rotman's book *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*, in the proof of Lemma 3.53,
[image]
I think we don't need the fact that $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is injective, because we don't have $0$'s in the extremities of the sequence $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$.

Comment: Are you sure? Consider $\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{p}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{\pi}{\to}\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ where $\pi(1)=p$ inthe last module, all considered as $\mathbb{Z}$ modules. This is exact, but if you apply $\mathrm{Hom}(*,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, you can see that all maps in the resulting seqience are zero and the sequence is not exact. So, in general, you will need the injectivity.

Comment: Yes you are right i see it now, thank you