# Misunderstanding on Rotman´s homological Lemma or mistake in the claim or proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $B$ a right module, we define the **character modules** $B^{\ast}$ as the left $R$ module $B^{\ast}:= Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(B, \frac{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Z}})$.

Rotman's Homological Algebra Lemma 3.53 sequence of right $R$ modules  claims the following statement:

A sequence of right modules $$\tag {1} A \xrightarrow{\alpha}B \xrightarrow{\beta} C $$

is exact if and only if the sequence of character modules

$$ \tag{2} C^{\ast} \xrightarrow{\beta^{\ast}}B^{\ast} \xrightarrow{\alpha^{\ast}} A^{\ast}$$

is exact.

To prove $\Rightarrow$ Rotman use the fact that since $\frac{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Z}}$ is injective, the functor $Hom(-,\frac{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Z}})$ is exact and so the sequence (2). Of course, this is true if  we have

$$0 \to A \xrightarrow{\alpha}B \xrightarrow{\beta} C \to 0 $$

instead of (1) and $$ 0 \to A^{\ast} \xrightarrow{\alpha^{\ast}}B^{\ast} \xrightarrow{\beta^{\ast}} C^{\ast} \to 0$$

instead of (2). I guess the proof of $(\Leftarrow)$ is OK since it is proven supposing that $(2)$ is exact, then $Im(\alpha) = Ker (\beta)$. I can't see (1) exact implies (2) according to Rotman´s argument, is there a mistake or typos in the Lemma? So we need to add some zeros to the sequences in the Lemma. Or how can I prove this. Thanks.

This one has been asked before in

[Lemma 3.53 Rotman's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406941/lemma-3-53-rotmans-an-introduction-to-homological-algebra)

But to be honest Im not convinced by the answer.

Comment: Well, I'd start by noting your own typo: $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(-, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is contravariant, so your arrows in the character modules are all backwards from what they should be...

Comment: After that, as long as I understand your question, the answer given here should work: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/803829 (I don't have my copy of Rotman handy to check it)

Comment: @BrianMoehring So according to the linked ME answer, it doesnt matter if we consider te zeros at the extreme of a sequence?

Comment: Yes, generally $\operatorname{Hom}(-,M)$ is contravariant and left-exact, in which case you need the $0$, but since $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is injective, $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(-,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is exact.  Since every exact sequence can be decomposed into short exact sequences as in the linked answer, an exact functor preserves exactness at every stage, not just for short exact sequences.